# How do i update canvas using js continuously?

Tags: javascript

I've got this piece of code that draws a ball and i want to continuously pass in different cooridinates in order to make it move around but when the refresh rate gets way too high, canvas stops updating. How do i force canvas to update and redraw everything with the arguments passed in?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("circle");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);




function determinePosition(x, y) {
  var trueX = x + 120;
  var trueY = y + 80;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(trueX, trueY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.stroke();
}
while(true){
determinePosition(x, y);
}
```

```html
<div class="gcircle">
  <canvas id="circle" width="240px" height="160"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `setInterval()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var c = document.getElementById("circle");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function determinePosition(x, y) {

  //clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  var trueX = x + 120;
  var trueY = y + 80;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(trueX, trueY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.stroke();
}

//set random location for each 0.5 sec
setInterval(function() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  determinePosition(x, y);
}, 500)
```

```html
<div class="gcircle">
  <canvas id="circle" width="240px" height="160"></canvas>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Drawing should always happen in a [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) loop. `requestAnimationFrame` runs at your monitor's refresh rate, so it's the fastest any animation can run. You can set it up like this:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("circle");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
var trueX = 0;
var trueY = 0;

function determinePosition(x, y) {
  trueX = x + 120;
  trueY = y + 80;
}

requestAnimationFrame(function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(trueX, trueY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.stroke();

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
})

determinePosition(x, y);
```